# Remove Chararcters from SQL Asset Number

Tags: sql

I work for a Vet's we are in the process of moving to a new system. Our IT guys aren't very helpful. We have a big list of assets of all our equipment, drugs etc. They each have an individual code.

Our asset codes are H01234, in the new system we need to remove the H0 part and

Example of our table 'as_asset'

```
as_asset_nbr char(6)   as_asset_desc varchar(50)
---------------------------------
H04116                  Desc 1
H04117                  Desc 1
H04118                  Desc 1
H04119                  Desc 1
```

We need to replae the as_asset_nbr and remove the H0 part. I've searched around and nothing I've tried seems to work.

If someone could help it would be amazing.

Thank you

Comment: This post shows zero effort.  A google search would have produced a ton of solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `REPLACE` function:

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(as_asset_nbr, 'H0', ''),
    as_asset_desc 
FROM as_asset
```